# How to use BodyGyro to point a part at a player?

Tags: lua, roblox

In ROBLOX LUA I am trying to make a spotlight that will follow a player. So far, it will not. I think I am scripting it wrong. I am trying to point a part at a part, as a proof of concept. Then I will make it point at a player, and then change it for a light. I'm not really sure how to start or approach this problem. I've tried to use BodyGyro.

I not really sure I m even trying it right. I have tryed putting my script into the part, and into starter player.

```
player = game.Players.LeugoKez
character = player.Character
hmndrootpart = character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
workspace.Spot.BodyGyro.CFrame = workspace.Spot.CFrame
while true do
    workspace.Spot.BodyGyro.CFrame = 
CFrame.new(workspace.Spot.Position, workspace.oof.Position)
wait(1)
end
```

I would like the script to point at a player, and be light, thus, a spotlight that will follow a player. So far, it does nothing. The script is in starter player, referencing the parts. The BodyGyro is inside the 'Spot' part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this line of code to help you;

```
bodyGyro.CFrame = CFrame.new(torso.Position, mouse.Hit.p)
```

Comment below if you need anything.

Ross.

Comment: If this answered your question, feel free to mark this as correct.